# how can I copy from a specific location of text file a string

Tags: c#

if I want a string from specific location in a text file, I copy text[i] to a char but how can I get from all the iteration a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Text File contains the following text:

```
Eitan Jacobs asked a question about C#. Someone voted it down.
```

Clearly the file size = 62 Bytes (as text length is 62 chars). Next say you want to read 5 bytes from 5th location onwards. You can read the file now like:

```
var buffer = new byte[5];
using(var fileStrm = File.OpenRead(<PathtoFile>))
{
     fileStrm.Read(buffer, 5, 5);
}

string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer); 
// If your string has different encoding use appropriate option
```

I wrote this code here itself, so ignore any syntax errors, but if this works text read from file will be "**Jacob**"